# How to sync php project between IDEs?

Tags: ide, flash-builder, zend-studio

I've been using NetBeans with xampp in windows Desktop. Now I start to learn Flash, as a consequence, I installed Flash Builder for PHP, Zend Server, and Zend Studio in windows laptop. I know I don't need to install those Zend stuffs, but FB provide nice intergration with Zend, So I think it might be more convinent.
Before I fully set my heart on FB+Zend in laptop, I still need to work on my project in NetBeans+xampp in desktop.

How to keep files in sync between the 2 setup? Or, if I am on the wrong path, please shade lights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using SVN or Git ? You can sync from those kind of repositories using netbeans if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm a newbie, write funny codes, if put them on Git, the whole world laughing.

Comment: Well you can always set up a private svn server on your computer, or better, use Google code hosting, you can keep projects private to other users

Comment: That's interesting. Let me try it out. Thanks!